# How to show images as automatic responsive size in grid/gallery view?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created this page using some resources. But i need images to be shown in the output picture.
Also the sidebar is automatically opening while loading page, i need to do close it by default.

i have tried to toggle class in JavaScript, but the closing animation is showing on once after page loads. this is pretty annoying.

```js
(function() {
  $('#msbo').on('click', function() {
    $('body').toggleClass('msb-x');
  });
}());
```

```css
.navbar-default {
  margin-left: 200px;
}

.msb {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #F5F7F9;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: auto;
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.msb .navbar {
  border: none;
  margin-left: 0;
  background-color: inherit;
}

.msb .navbar-header {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background: #fff;
}

.msb .navbar-nav .panel {
  border: 0 none;
  box-shadow: none;
  margin: 0;
  background: inherit;
}

.msb .navbar-nav li {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.msb .navbar-nav li a {
  padding: 15px;
  color: #5f5f5f;
}

.msb .navbar-nav li a .glyphicon,
.msb .navbar-nav li a .fa {
  margin-right: 8px;
}

.msb .nb {
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

ul.nv,
ul.ns {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.nv {
  /*ns: nav-sub*/
}

.nv li {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.nv li::before {
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.nv li a {
  color: #444;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  display: block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.nv li a .ic {
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  font-weight: 300;
  display: inline-block;
}

.nv .ns li a {
  padding: 10px 50px;
}


/*main content wrapper*/

.mcw {
  margin-left: 200px;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
  /*content view*/
}


/*globals*/

a,
a:focus,
a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.inbox .container-fluid {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}

.inbox ul,
.inbox li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.inbox ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

.inbox ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.msb,
.mnb {
  -moz-animation: slidein 300ms forwards;
  -o-animation: slidein 300ms forwards;
  -webkit-animation: slidein 300ms forwards;
  animation: slidein 300ms forwards;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.mcw {
  -moz-animation: bodyslidein 300ms forwards;
  -o-animation: bodyslidein 300ms forwards;
  -webkit-animation: bodyslidein 300ms forwards;
  animation: bodyslidein 300ms forwards;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

body.msb-x .mcw,
body.msb-x .mnb {
  margin-left: 0;
  -moz-animation: bodyslideout 300ms forwards;
  -o-animation: bodyslideout 300ms forwards;
  -webkit-animation: bodyslideout 300ms forwards;
  animation: bodyslideout 300ms forwards;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

body.msb-x .msb {
  -moz-animation: slideout 300ms forwards;
  -o-animation: slideout 300ms forwards;
  -webkit-animation: slideout 300ms forwards;
  animation: slideout 300ms forwards;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}


/* Slide in animation */

@-moz-keyframes slidein {
  0% {
    left: -200px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slidein {
  0% {
    left: -200px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes slidein {
  0% {
    left: -200px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes slideout {
  0% {
    left: 0;
  }
  100% {
    left: -200px;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideout {
  0% {
    left: 0;
  }
  100% {
    left: -200px;
  }
}

@keyframes slideout {
  0% {
    left: 0;
  }
  100% {
    left: -200px;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes bodyslidein {
  0% {
    left: 0;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: 200px;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes bodyslidein {
  0% {
    left: 0;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes bodyslidein {
  0% {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: 200px;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes bodyslideout {
  0% {
    margin-left: 200px;
  }
  100% {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes bodyslideout {
  0% {
    margin-left: 200px;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes bodyslideout {
  0% {
    margin-left: 200px;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}

.video-list-thumbs>li {
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.video-list-thumbs>li>a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #111;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.video-list-thumbs>li>a:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  text-decoration: none
}

.video-list-thumbs h2 {
  bottom: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 33px;
  margin: 8px 0 0;
}

.video-list-thumbs .glyphicon-play-circle {
  font-size: 60px;
  opacity: 0.6;
  position: absolute;
  right: 39%;
  top: 31%;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
}

.video-list-thumbs>li>a:hover .glyphicon-play-circle {
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 1;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
}

.video-list-thumbs .duration {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  left: 12px;
  line-height: 13px;
  padding: 2px 3px 1px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;
  transition: all 500ms ease;
}

.video-list-thumbs>li>a:hover .duration {
  background-color: #000;
}

@media (min-width:320px) and (max-width: 480px) {
  .video-list-thumbs .glyphicon-play-circle {
    font-size: 35px;
    right: 36%;
    top: 27%;
  }
  .video-list-thumbs h2 {
    bottom: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 22px;
    margin: 8px 0 0;
  }
}

body {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  letter-spacing: 0.01em;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <title>Video Visualizer</title>

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700,800,900" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body style="background-color: #f2f3f3;">

  <nav class="mnb navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <div style="padding: 8px 0;">
        <a href="#" id="msbo"><i class="ic fa fa-bars"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </nav>



  <div class="msb" id="msb">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <div class="brand-wrapper">
          <div class="brand-name-wrapper">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                            Video Visualizer
                        </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="side-menu-container">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-puzzle-piece"></i> Components</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i> Extras</a></li>

        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>


  <div class="mcw">

    <div class="container">
      <br>
      <ul class="list-unstyled video-list-thumbs row">
        <li class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
          <a class="modalclick" href="https://archive.org/download/WebmVp8Vorbis/webmvp8_512kb.mp4" title="Claudio Bravo, antes su">
            <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/4111719/pexels-photo-4111719.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" alt="Barca" class="img-responsive" width="100%" height="100%" />
            <h2>Claudio Bravo, antes su </h2>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle"></span>
            <!-- <span class="duration">03:15</span> -->
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
          <a class="modalclick" href="https://archive.org/download/WebmVp8Vorbis/webmvp8_512kb.mp4" title="Claudiocon el Barça en la Liga">
            <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1991933/pexels-photo-1991933.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&w=500" alt="Barca" class="img-responsive" width="100%" height="100%" />
            <h2>Claudiocon el Barça en la Liga</h2>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle"></span>
            <!-- <span class="duration">03:15</span> -->
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
          <a class="modalclick" href="https://archive.org/download/WebmVp8Vorbis/webmvp8_512kb.mp4" title="Bravo, antesa">
            <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/5593847/pexels-photo-5593847.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&w=500" alt="Barca" class="img-responsive" width="100%" height="100%" />
            <h2>Bravo, antesa</h2>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle"></span>
            <!-- <span class="duration">03:15</span> -->
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
          <a class="modalclick" href="https://archive.org/download/WebmVp8Vorbis/webmvp8_512kb.mp4" title="Claudio la Liga">
            <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/3029023/pexels-photo-3029023.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&w=500" alt="Barca" class="img-responsive" width="100%" height="100%" />
            <h2>Claudio la Liga</h2>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle"></span>
            <!-- <span class="duration">03:15</span> -->
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
          <a class="modalclick" href="https://archive.org/download/WebmVp8Vorbis/webmvp8_512kb.mp4" title="Barça en la Liga">
            <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/3016317/pexels-photo-3016317.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" alt="Barca" class="img-responsive" width="100%" height="100%" />
            <h2>Barça en la Liga</h2>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle"></span>
            <!-- <span class="duration">03:15</span> -->
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
          <a class="modalclick" href="https://archive.org/download/WebmVp8Vorbis/webmvp8_512kb.mp4" title="Bravo Barça en la Liga">
            <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/5255552/pexels-photo-5255552.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" alt="Barca" class="img-responsive" width="100%" height="100%" />
            <h2>Bravo Barça en la Liga</h2>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle"></span>
            <!-- <span class="duration">03:15</span> -->
          </a>
        </li>

      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"></h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span
                            aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <video controls id="video1" style="width: 100%; height: auto; margin:0 auto; frameborder:0;">
                        <source src="" type="video/mp4">
                    </video>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Actual:**

[image]

**Expected:**

[image]

Comment: For this, you have to use the Masonry effect, check here https://masonry.desandro.com/layout.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use flex-box flex-direction and set it to column.

```
.mcw .container ul {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      height: 100VH;
      align-content: flex-start;
     }
```

This will make the items go down the page and you will need to play around with the height to get more columns. But as you can see it works by using full screen and resizing the browser window.

You will need to override some of the bootstrap classes too. The ones below aren't really needed or need to be overridden or unset as shown.

unset flex in these 2 classes.

```
.col-lg-3 {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 25%;
  flex: unset;
  max-width: 25%;
}

.col-sm-4 {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 33.333333%;
  flex: unset;
  max-width: 33.333333%;
}
```

```js
(function() {
  $('#msbo').on('click', function() {
    $('body').toggleClass('msb-x');
  });
}());
```

```css
.navbar-default {
  margin-left: 200px;
}

.msb {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #F5F7F9;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: auto;
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.msb .navbar {
  border: none;
  margin-left: 0;
  background-color: inherit;
}

.msb .navbar-header {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background: #fff;
}

.msb .navbar-nav .panel {
  border: 0 none;
  box-shadow: none;
  margin: 0;
  background: inherit;
}

.msb .navbar-nav li {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.msb .navbar-nav li a {
  padding: 15px;
  color: #5f5f5f;
}

.msb .navbar-nav li a .glyphicon,
.msb .navbar-nav li a .fa {
  margin-right: 8px;
}

.msb .nb {
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

ul.nv,
ul.ns {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.nv {
  /*ns: nav-sub*/
}

.nv li {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.nv li::before {
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.nv li a {
  color: #444;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  display: block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.nv li a .ic {
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  font-weight: 300;
  display: inline-block;
}

.nv .ns li a {
  padding: 10px 50px;
}


/*main content wrapper*/

.mcw {
  margin-left: 200px;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
  /*content view*/
}

.mcw .container ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 80VH;
  align-content: flex-start;
 }

col-lg-3 {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 25%;
  flex:unset!important;
  max-width: 25%;
}

.col-sm-4 {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 33.333333%;
  flex: unset!important;
  max-width: 33.333333%;
}
     


/*globals*/

a,
a:focus,
a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.inbox .container-fluid {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}

.inbox ul,
.inbox li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.inbox ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

.inbox ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.msb,
.mnb {
  -moz-animation: slidein 300ms forwards;
  -o-animation: slidein 300ms forwards;
  -webkit-animation: slidein 300ms forwards;
  animation: slidein 300ms forwards;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.mcw {
  -moz-animation: bodyslidein 300ms forwards;
  -o-animation: bodyslidein 300ms forwards;
  -webkit-animation: bodyslidein 300ms forwards;
  animation: bodyslidein 300ms forwards;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

body.msb-x .mcw,
body.msb-x .mnb {
  margin-left: 0;
  -moz-animation: bodyslideout 300ms forwards;
  -o-animation: bodyslideout 300ms forwards;
  -webkit-animation: bodyslideout 300ms forwards;
  animation: bodyslideout 300ms forwards;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

body.msb-x .msb {
  -moz-animation: slideout 300ms forwards;
  -o-animation: slideout 300ms forwards;
  -webkit-animation: slideout 300ms forwards;
  animation: slideout 300ms forwards;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}


/* Slide in animation */

@-moz-keyframes slidein {
  0% {
    left: -200px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slidein {
  0% {
    left: -200px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes slidein {
  0% {
    left: -200px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes slideout {
  0% {
    left: 0;
  }
  100% {
    left: -200px;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideout {
  0% {
    left: 0;
  }
  100% {
    left: -200px;
  }
}

@keyframes slideout {
  0% {
    left: 0;
  }
  100% {
    left: -200px;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes bodyslidein {
  0% {
    left: 0;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: 200px;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes bodyslidein {
  0% {
    left: 0;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes bodyslidein {
  0% {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: 200px;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes bodyslideout {
  0% {
    margin-left: 200px;
  }
  100% {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes bodyslideout {
  0% {
    margin-left: 200px;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes bodyslideout {
  0% {
    margin-left: 200px;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}

.video-list-thumbs>li {
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.video-list-thumbs>li>a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #111;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.video-list-thumbs>li>a:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  text-decoration: none
}

.video-list-thumbs h2 {
  bottom: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 33px;
  margin: 8px 0 0;
}

.video-list-thumbs .glyphicon-play-circle {
  font-size: 60px;
  opacity: 0.6;
  position: absolute;
  right: 39%;
  top: 31%;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
}

.video-list-thumbs>li>a:hover .glyphicon-play-circle {
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 1;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
}

.video-list-thumbs .duration {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  left: 12px;
  line-height: 13px;
  padding: 2px 3px 1px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;
  transition: all 500ms ease;
}

.video-list-thumbs>li>a:hover .duration {
  background-color: #000;
}

@media (min-width:320px) and (max-width: 480px) {
  .video-list-thumbs .glyphicon-play-circle {
    font-size: 35px;
    right: 36%;
    top: 27%;
  }
  .video-list-thumbs h2 {
    bottom: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 22px;
    margin: 8px 0 0;
  }
}

body {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  letter-spacing: 0.01em;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <title>Video Visualizer</title>

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700,800,900" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body style="background-color: #f2f3f3;">

  <nav class="mnb navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <div style="padding: 8px 0;">
        <a href="#" id="msbo"><i class="ic fa fa-bars"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </nav>



  <div class="msb" id="msb">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <div class="brand-wrapper">
          <div class="brand-name-wrapper">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                            Video Visualizer
                        </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="side-menu-container">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-puzzle-piece"></i> Components</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i> Extras</a></li>

        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>


  <div class="mcw">

    <div class="container">
      <br>
      <ul class="list-unstyled video-list-thumbs row">
        <li class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
          <a class="modalclick" href="https://archive.org/download/WebmVp8Vorbis/webmvp8_512kb.mp4" title="Claudio Bravo, antes su">
            <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/4111719/pexels-photo-4111719.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" alt="Barca" class="img-responsive" width="100%" height="100%" />
            <h2>Claudio Bravo, antes su </h2>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle"></span>
            <!-- <span class="duration">03:15</span> -->
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
          <a class="modalclick" href="https://archive.org/download/WebmVp8Vorbis/webmvp8_512kb.mp4" title="Claudiocon el Barça en la Liga">
            <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1991933/pexels-photo-1991933.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&w=500" alt="Barca" class="img-responsive" width="100%" height="100%" />
            <h2>Claudiocon el Barça en la Liga</h2>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle"></span>
            <!-- <span class="duration">03:15</span> -->
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
          <a class="modalclick" href="https://archive.org/download/WebmVp8Vorbis/webmvp8_512kb.mp4" title="Bravo, antesa">
            <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/5593847/pexels-photo-5593847.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&w=500" alt="Barca" class="img-responsive" width="100%" height="100%" />
            <h2>Bravo, antesa</h2>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle"></span>
            <!-- <span class="duration">03:15</span> -->
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
          <a class="modalclick" href="https://archive.org/download/WebmVp8Vorbis/webmvp8_512kb.mp4" title="Claudio la Liga">
            <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/3029023/pexels-photo-3029023.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&w=500" alt="Barca" class="img-responsive" width="100%" height="100%" />
            <h2>Claudio la Liga</h2>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle"></span>
            <!-- <span class="duration">03:15</span> -->
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
          <a class="modalclick" href="https://archive.org/download/WebmVp8Vorbis/webmvp8_512kb.mp4" title="Barça en la Liga">
            <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/3016317/pexels-photo-3016317.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" alt="Barca" class="img-responsive" width="100%" height="100%" />
            <h2>Barça en la Liga</h2>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle"></span>
            <!-- <span class="duration">03:15</span> -->
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
          <a class="modalclick" href="https://archive.org/download/WebmVp8Vorbis/webmvp8_512kb.mp4" title="Bravo Barça en la Liga">
            <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/5255552/pexels-photo-5255552.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" alt="Barca" class="img-responsive" width="100%" height="100%" />
            <h2>Bravo Barça en la Liga</h2>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle"></span>
            <!-- <span class="duration">03:15</span> -->
          </a>
        </li>

      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"></h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span
                            aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <video controls id="video1" style="width: 100%; height: auto; margin:0 auto; frameborder:0;">
                        <source src="" type="video/mp4">
                    </video>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is a sample preview

[image]

Comment: it sets the container to 100VH which is view height. when viewed at full screen it works. In the small preview above it does show in one row as the view height of the previewer is less than an image.

Comment: can u share the fiddle link?

Comment: I added a preview, in the post. Can you use Run Code Snippet and the Full page functionality in Stack Overflow, please?

Comment: You might also need to/ can add media queries to control at different screen sizes, the code sample supplied illustrates how flex-direction: column can be used.

Comment: Got it works, but in desktop i get a vertical scroll bar, when i click side navbar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223786/discussion-between-simon-and-sathish-kumar).

Comment: @SathishKumar did you get this to work? you can use overflow: hidden to remove scroll bar. But I think this is not an issue with the display of the image in the grid but more one of the navbar sizing.